# Why are the ends of Tefilin Retzuos cut on a slant?

Tags: minhag, tefilin

I noticed than the end of my Tefillin Retzuos are cut on a slant. In the comments to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1973/cutting-tefillin-retzuos/1975#1975) various reasons are postulated. What is the true reason?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe to make them easier to thread through the maavarta (the "channel" at the back of the tefillin casing)?